# Can not log out of Google Account: 52.0.2 (32-bit) Windows 10

Tags: firefox, cookies

Attempts to follow instructions to remedy the cookie error message failed:

[image]

Seeking remedies from those who have recently overcome this problem on the same platform configuration.  Thank you

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this problem on any of my 32-bit virtual machines.  have you contacted your IT Administrator for assistance?  You should verify your proxy settings are correct also.  Does IE11, Edge, and Chrome work?

Comment: Edge and IE did not suffer the symptom.  Days later the problem disappears after numerous reboots.  Weird..